# MVC 5 [HttpPost] attribute or post inside the form tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and I was wondering what's the difference between the attribute [HttpPost] and the post method inside the form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="something" />
    <input type="text" name="something" value="something"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

? Are they the same thing or... I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post">  </form>
```

Here the `method="post"` is **not an ASP.NET MVC thing**. It is normal HTML [form tag specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) where it tells that when the form is submitted, it will use the POST method (rather than GET where form data is submitted as querystring values). When you use POST, the form data will be part of the request BODY.

In the ASP.NET MVC world, the attribute decorator `[HttpPost]` tells the framework that the action method (on which we used this decorator) is for handling a request coming from the client(browser) of type "POST" (the form method). This helps the framework to read the data from the request body and use that as needed (For Model binding etc)

In short, both are different things. One is one client side and other is on your server code. But you usually use it together to build a client side form and a server side method to handle the submitted form.

Comment: `[HttpPost]` is known as an action filter. There are others for other HTTP methods.

Comment: @Shyju I know that by default it's like I use [HttpGet]... So what happens if I don't write [HttpPost]?? I like the part"This helps the framework to read the data from the request body and use that as needed (For Model binding etc)"... Can I get some more info?

Comment: Like i mentioned in the answer, the form data will be send to server in the request body when using POST method & as query string key values (which you can see in the browser url) when using GET. Server should know where to read the form data from.